# restrict access to subdirectory in apache, leaving parent open

Tags: apache2, webdav, http-basic-authentication

I am setting a webdav on apache2.4 and I need for my top directory  `/webdav` to be freely open  and for a sub directory like `/webdav/projects/secretproject` to be protected with a password.

My curremt `dav.conf` looks like this

```
Alias /webdav /var/webdav/
Alias /secretproject /webdav/projects/secretproject/ 
<Location /webdav/projects/secretproject >
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "TEST - TEST"
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/auth/test.passwd"

   <RequireAll>
       Require all granted
       Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</Location>

 <Location /webdav >
     DAV on
     Options +Indexes
     <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>
          Deny from all
      </LimitExcept>
      Require all granted
 </Location>

 <Directory /var/webdav/ >
      Options Indexes 
      FollowSymLinksAllow from all
 </Directory>
```

I undestand that permissions merge from the most generic `/`, `/webdav` to the most specific `/webdav/projects/secretproject`

According to this issue

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404034/restrict-access-to-subdirectory-in-apache

My permissions need to be rapped with `<RequireAll>` to force the `Require valid-user` to be imposed and therefore the subdirectory locked (otherwise the `Require all granted` will overrule any restriction)

Unfortunately the subdirectory is unrestricted with this configuration and I would like to understand why. Any suggestions on how to restrict a subdirectory are also helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this (apache2 2.4.18) and found out that basic authentication works as soon as I change `Location` to `Directory` like this:

```
<Directory /var/webdav/projects/secretproject >
…
</Directory>
```

I think that is because the `Directory` directive for `/var/webdav` overrides the `Location` directive for projects/secretproject, but I'm not sure about this.

Furthermore you have a little typo in that config, it should correctly read:

```
<Directory /var/webdav/ >
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But since your apache2 is running I think this is only a copy-paste error from putting it here on serverfault. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,  I haven't tested (yet) but a collegue has tested and said it was working. I will then post a full example

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the previous comments, implementing the `auth` inside the directory without location solved the problem

```
Alias /webdav /var/webdav/
Alias /secretproject /webdav/projects/secretproject/ 
<Directory /webdav/projects/secretproject >
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "TEST - TEST"
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/auth/test.passwd"
<RequireAll>
   Require all granted
   Require valid-user
</RequireAll>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/webdav/ >
    DAV on
    Options +Indexes
    FollowSymLinks from all
    <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Thank you for the help